# AWS S3 403 Forbidden Error on newly created IAM inline policy for a new IAM user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-iam, fog

I have a brand new IAM user that I want to give upload & read access to my newly created bucket - `myapp`.

This is the policy I am using for my user now:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this policy, I can login to the console, I can create folders and I can upload images to these folders.

However, when I attempt to upload an image through my app, this is what I get:

```
Excon::Errors::Forbidden at /jobs
Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
excon.error.response
  :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>0FF1D4848595DCFB</RequestId><HostId>+RrQvNFwV2hAcYPK3ZJJYzy5uiA7Aag0oc1Gpp3hENJ9lzJz453j8qJeLbdQ8jN4cc3ViRJ1lEg=</HostId></Error>"
  :cookies       => [
  ]
  :headers       => {
    "Connection"       => "close"
    "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
    "Date"             => "Sat, 25 Jun 2016 18:54:24 GMT"
    "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
    "x-amz-id-2"       => "+R3ViRJ1lEg="
    "x-amz-request-id" => "0FF1DCFB"
  }
  :host          => "s3.amazonaws.com"
  :local_address => "192.168.1.102"
  :local_port    => 23456
  :path          => "/logos/company/logo/48/amped-logo.png"
  :port          => 443
  :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
  :remote_ip     => "xx.xx.xxx.xxx"
  :status        => 403
  :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
```

Here are my CORS rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This is my `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb` file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:               'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:      ENV["MYAPP_S3_KEY"],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["MYAPP_SECRET_KEY"]
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["MYBUCKET"]
end
```

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually just figured it out, and it was one small thing.

All I had to do was add `"s3:PutObjectAcl"` to my policy.

So now, my policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And now that works.

I got the tip from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719942/91970), which saved my bacon.